# If L* is context-free, is L context-free as well?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I know CFL in closed under Closure, but don't know how to prove it back.

I try to construct a CFG for L* such as S->ε|AS and say since L* in a context-free language, there must exist a method to build grammar A. So then we can use A to construct another CFG to represent L and prove L must be context-free.

But I believe it is not a convincing proof. Can anyone please give some proof or counter example?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $L_0$ be a language over $\{a,b,c\}$ that is not context-free, and let $L=\{a,b,c\}\cup L_0$, which is of course also not context-free. What is $L^*$? Note that it is possible to answer this without knowing **anything** about $L_0$ beyond the fact that it is over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$.

I’ve added a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below; mouse over it to see it.

> Since the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ is a subset of $L$, clearly $\{a,b,c\}^*\subseteq L^*$.

Comment: Well, suppose L0={a^n b^n c^n | n≥1}. That is not context-free and we can prove with pumping lemma....But {a,b,c}∪L0 will still fail while applying pumping lemma, which means {a,b,c}∪L0 is actually not context-free as well.

Comment: Can you please give more details? Since L*=L+L+L...not L∪L. Sorry but I cannot get your point.

Comment: @TawcherBro: Of course $\{a,b,c\}\cup L_0$ is not context-free: that’s exactly the point! Now, what is the language $L^*$? It’s very simple, and you should be able to tell me exactly what words are in it and from that what kind of language it is. An added hint: you don’t need to know anything about $L_0$ to figure out what $L^*$ is.

Comment: Then the expression that can be accepted by L* can be arbitrary combination of {a,b,c}, and L* can be represented by something like S->ε|aS|bS|cS, so it is context-free even if L is not. Did I get it?

Comment: @TawcherBro: Yes: $L^*=\{a,b,c\}^*$, and that language is not just context-free, but even regular. Thus, taking the Kleene star of a language $L$ can give you a language that is as nice as possible even when $L$ is very complicated.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much ! Sometimes I really feel that I am using inspiration rather than my poor experience to solve problems related to computing theory. They are still like some magic XD.

Comment: @TawcherBro: You’re welcome!

Comment: Nice argument, but it works equally well with a one letter alphabet.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: And at this point I have **no** idea why I rather arbitrarily used a 3-letter alphabet.